# pyQt5 with QThread programm runs as many times as many times as I run

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        loadUi('wind.ui', self)
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.start_screen)
        self.stopButton.clicked.connect(self.stop_screen)
        self.screen_thread = Screenshot()

    def start_screen(self):
        self.screen_thread.start()
        self.screen_thread.any_signal.connect(self.myfunction)

    def stop_screen(self):
        self.screen_thread.stop()

    def myfunction(self,value):
        vl = value
        print(vl, threading.active_count())

class Screenshot(QThread):
    any_signal = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Screenshot, self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):

        value = 1
        print('process start')
        print(threading.active_count())
        print(threading.enumerate())
        while(True):
            value += 1
            time.sleep(1)
            self.any_signal.emit(value)

    def stop(self):
        print('process stop')
        self.terminate()
        print(self.isRunning())

def application():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application()
```

There are two start and stop buttons. when I run it for the first time, everything is ok, the value is printed once and incremented. then I press stop, everything stops. when I press start a second time, the result is printed twice. the third time three times, and so on. I thought that new threads were being added and entered a command to monitor threads. but only one thread is shown each time. where is the mistake?

Comment: standard rule: if you need many elements then you should `append()`  them on list, not assign to the same variable.

Comment: Move the connection to `any_signal` in the `__init__`. Also, don't use `terminate()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought that new threads were being added and entered a command to monitor threads. but only one thread is shown each time.

Only one thread is shown each time because you only create one thread:  `self.screen_thread = Screenshot()`

Each time you click the start button it starts the thread (calling `.start()` once a thread has started does nothing), and it connects the `self.myfunction` slot to the `any_signal`. Because you can connect the same slot multiple times to the same signal, it just gets called multiple times.

If you want multiple threads, then you will need to create them, and keep track of them. Something like this should do:

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        loadUi('wind.ui', self)
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.start_screen)
        self.stopButton.clicked.connect(self.stop_screen)
        self.threads = []

    def start_screen(self):
        thread = Screenshot()
        thread.any_signal.connect(self.myfunction)
        thread.start()
        self.threads.append(thread)

    def stop_screen(self):
        for thread in self.threads:
            thread.stop()
        
        self.threads = []

    def myfunction(self,value):
        vl = value
        print(vl, threading.active_count())

class Screenshot(QThread):
    any_signal = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Screenshot, self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):

        value = 1
        print('process start')
        print(threading.active_count())
        print(threading.enumerate())
        while(True):
            value += 1
            time.sleep(1)
            self.any_signal.emit(value)

    def stop(self):
        print('process stop')
        self.terminate()
        print(self.isRunning())

def application():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application()
```

Note that the use of [`QThread.terminate`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#terminate) is discouraged:

> Warning: This function is dangerous and its use is discouraged. The thread can be terminated at any point in its code path. Threads can be terminated while modifying data. There is no chance for the thread to clean up after itself, unlock any held mutexes, etc. In short, use this function only if absolutely necessary.

Instead, call [`QThread.requestInterruption`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#requestInterruption) and regularly check for an interruption request within the thread with [`QThread.isInterruptionRequested`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#isInterruptionRequested).

Comment: no i dont need multiple threads. i want it print 1 time every time when i press start button

Comment: thank you for explanation about connect the same slot multiple times to the same signal. i just move thread.any_signal.connect(self.myfunction) to the __Init__ of the class. all works fine. and now i use request interruption instead terminate. and for the future how i can disconnect signal from slot?

Comment: Use the signals `.diconnect()` method. For example: `self.screen_thread.any_signal.disconnect(self.myfunction)`. With no arguments it disconnects all slots from the signal.